# Manual cross validation in Ridge regression results in same MSE for every lambda

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm building a Ridge regression and am trying to tune the regularization parameter through [Forward Chaining](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) Cross validation as Im dealing with time series data. My code is as follows:

```
mse_avg_ridge = []
for alph in range(0,100,1):
    mse = []
    rd = Ridge(random_state=0, alpha=alph/100)
    for i in range(30,153,30): ##there are 153 observations 
        X_cross = X[0:i]
        Y_cross = Y[0:i]
        rd.fit(X_cross, Y_cross)
        X_cross_test = X[i:153]
        Y_cross_test = Y[i:153]
        mse.append(np.mean(np.square(rf.predict(X_cross_test)-Y_cross_test)))
    mse_avg_ridge.append((alph/100,np.mean(mse)))
```

Somehow, `mse_avg_ridge` gives me the same value for every alpha as follows:

`[(0.0, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.01, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.02, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.03, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.04, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.05, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.06, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.07, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.08, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.09, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.1, 0.0006005114839775559), (0.11, 0.0006005114839775559).......]`

I cant understand why.

Comment: I guess there shouldn't be second `mean`.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda The `mse` lists still appear to be the same for each of the `alpha` values

Comment: I was wrong there is nothing about second `mean`. Try to check on another data. I executed your code with randomly generated `X` and `Y` and `np.mean(mse)` I obtained slightly differs.Check if your `X` is scaled.Try to use option `normalize` from `Ridge`.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Thanks, but I scaled it already via `X =preprocessing.scale(X)`. I didn't look to `normalize` as I wanted to maintain some interpretability but I would think this shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you use rd as the name of Ridge regression, but in calculating the mse, you use rf.predict (could be something you trained before?)